# Issue using Generic Maps in Java

Tags: java, generics, maps

I have a class which I am trying to use to test HashMap and TreeMap, shown below;

```
public class TestMap<KeyType, ValueType>
{
private Map<KeyType, ValueType> internalMap;

/*
 * Entry point for the application
 */
public static void main( String [ ] args )
{
    TestMap<String, Integer> testHashMap = new TestMap<String,Integer>(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
    testHashMap.test();

    TestMap<String, Integer> testTreeMap = new TestMap<String,Integer>(new TreeMap<String, Integer>());
    testTreeMap.test();
}    

/*
 * Constructor which accepts a generic Map for testing
 */
public TestMap(Map<KeyType, ValueType> m)
{
    this.internalMap = m;
}   

public void test()
{
    try
    {
        //put some values into the Map
        this.internalMap.put("Pittsburgh Steelers", 6);

        this.printMap("Tested Map", this.internalMap);  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

}

In the attempted call to the put() method I am receiving the below error message;

> The method put(KeyType, ValueType) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (String, int)

I am not receiving any other warnings, and I don't understand why I am getting this?  Isn't this the entire point of generics?  To define generically and implement concretely?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: As an aside, generic type parameters are normally restricted to being single capital letter eg. `public class MyClass<T> {`. Normally `E` or `T` is used, and for Maps `K` and `V` are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `test()` method is part of the `TestMap` class. In any of the `TestMap` methods, you can only reference the generic type, not any specific type (because this depends on the individual instance). However, you can do this:

```
public static void main( String [ ] args )
{
    TestMap<String, Integer> testHashMap = new TestMap<String,Integer>(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
    testHashMap.internalMap.put("Pittsburgh Steelers", 6);

    TestMap<String, Integer> testTreeMap = new TestMap<String,Integer>(new TreeMap<String, Integer>());
    testTreeMap.internalMap.put("Pittsburgh Steelers", 6);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your overall class is generic, but you are trying to test it with a specific set of types. Try moving the test method out of the object and using it on a `TestMap<String, int>`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to remove the generics from your TestMap object. They don't currently seem to be doing anything.

```
public class TestMap {
    private Map<String, Integer> internalMap;

    /*
     * Entry point for the application
     */
    public static void main( String [ ] args )
    {
        TestMap testHashMap = new TestMap(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
        testHashMap.test();

        TestMap testTreeMap = new TestMap(new TreeMap<String, Integer>());
        testTreeMap.test();
    }

    /*
     * Constructor which accepts a generic Map for testing
     */
    public TestMap(Map<String, Integer> m)
    {
        this.internalMap = m;
    }   

    public void test()
    {
        try
        {
            //put some values into the Map
            this.internalMap.put("Pittsburgh Steelers", 6);

            this.printMap("Tested Map", this.internalMap);  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my thought as well... but according to my professor and grader, TestMap should be "Generic", and I should be able to test both a HashMap and TreeMap by only instantiating an instance of TestMap with each, and then calling test().

Comment: In that case your test method could create test variables depending on what class KeyType and ValueType are.